# How to calculate Average Term Length By Initial Character in java?

Tags: java

I have a file (txt) with a paragraph of text in it and I have to calculate Average term length by initial character in java. For example if there's 4 words "purple, brown, pink, black" outputs should be;
p = 5
b = 5

I'm thinking of it for hours but I couldn't do it
All I could do was just splittin the words. I have no idea how I can do a list of words with same initial character.

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("sampleText.txt"))) {

            ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {

                String sampleText = scanner.nextLine();

                String[] array = sampleText.split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    if (array[i].charAt(0) = Integer ) //tried to not take numbers didn't work

                    System.out.println(array[i]);

                    arrlist.add(array[i]);
                }

                System.out.print(array);

                break;

            }

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FNF Exception");
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
            System.out.println("AIOoB Exception");
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is `5` and `5` both have a total characters 10 if I well understood him.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス Yes, you're right

Comment: Try using a `Map<Character, List<String>>`, then you can group each word based on the first character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in this way:

1. Split the string on comma followed by whitespace (i.e. `,\\s+`), store the produced strings into a `List<String>` and then sort the list.
2. Use a `Map<Character, Double>` to store the calculated data in which the key will be the initial character and the value will be the average term length.
3. Use variables to calculate the sum and count the elements so that you can calculate the average. Using an inner loop, navigate the list until you get an element with a different initial letter.
4. Terminate the inner loop as soon as you get an element with a different initial letter. At this point, store the initial letter with the average into the map.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "purple, brown, pink, black";

        // Split the string and store into a List<String>
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(",\\s+"));

        // Sort the list
        list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

        // Use a Map<String, Integer> to store the data
        Map<Character, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            // Get the element and move to the loop counter to the next index
            String element = list.get(i++);

            double sum = element.length();
            Character ch = Character.valueOf(element.charAt(0));
            int count = 1;

            // Starting with the next index, iterate the list until you find an element with
            // a different initial letter
            while (i < list.size() && ch.equals(Character.valueOf(list.get(i).charAt(0)))) {
                // Add the length of element and move the outer loop counter to the next index
                sum += list.get(i++).length();
                count++;
            }

            map.put(ch, sum / count);

            // Adjust the the outer loop counter by decrementing by 1
            i--;
        }

        // Display the result
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{b=5.0, p=5.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is allowed to use Java Streams, this task can be resolved using Collectors:

- `groupingBy`: to group by the initial character
- `mappingBy`: keep the words
- `averagingInt`: calculate average length of words

Also, `filter` may be used to consider only "valid" words (containing only letters)

```java
static Map<Character, Double> getAverageLengths(String line) {
    return getAverageLengths(Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")));
}

static Map<Character, Double> getAverageLengths(Stream<String> words) {
    return words.filter(w -> w.matches("[A-Za-z]+"))  // the words containing at least 1 letter
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.charAt(0), 
                        Collectors.mapping(w -> w, Collectors.averagingInt(String::length))));
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(getAverageLengths(
    Arrays.asList("purple", "brown", "pink", "black", "azure", "123", "$abc").stream()
));
System.out.println(getAverageLengths("orange apple and almond are appetizers"));
```

Output:

```
{p=5.0, b=5.0, a=5.0}
{a=5.4, o=6.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could group each word by its first character

```
Map<Character, List<String>> = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : array) {
    List<Integer> l;
    Character c = word.charAt(0);
    if (m.containsKey(c)) {
        l = m.get(c);
    } else {
        l = new ArrayList<>();
        m.put(c, l); 
    }
    l.add(word.length()); 
}
```

Now you have a mapping of characters to word lengths starting with that character that you can average